# About the Lemma on pp. 107-108 of Walter's Ordinary Differential Equations

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working through this material and I've hit something I fail to understand. The first two parts of the lemma on page 108-109 are clear, but in part c), page 109, we have this sentence (more or less--I've edited slightly for length and context):

> Because K is compact, we may assume that (x<sub>k</sub>, **y<sub>k</sub>**) --> (x<sub>0</sub>, **y<sub>0</sub>**), *and since *f* is bounded in K, it follows from |**f**(x<sub>k</sub>, **y<sub>k</sub>**) - **f**(x<sub>k</sub>, **z<sub>k</sub>**)| >= k|**y<sub>k</sub>** - **z<sub>k</sub>**| (k = 1, 2, ...) that (x<sub>k</sub>, **z<sub>k</sub>**) tends to the same point.*

I do not see why the italicized part follows. Simply because *f* (and shouldn't that be **f**?) is bounded in K, it does not follow that "(x<sub>k</sub>, **z<sub>k</sub>**) tends to the same point", assuming that "the same point" means (x<sub>0</sub>, **y<sub>0</sub>**). Am I misunderstanding the math or the language?

UPDATE--Here's a fuller quote:

**V. Lemma.** ...c) If **f** an element of *C(D)* satisfies in *D* a local Lipschitz condition in **y**, then **f** satisfies a Lipschitz condition in **y** on compact subsets of *D*.

**Proof.** ...c) If *K* a subset of *D* is compact and the proposition with respect to *K* is false, then there exist sequences (x<sub>k</sub>, **y**<sub>k</sub>), (x<sub>k</sub>, **z**<sub>k</sub>) in *K* with |**f**(x<sub>k</sub>, **y**<sub>k</sub>) - **f**(x<sub>k</sub>, **z**<sub>k</sub>)| >= k|**y**<sub>k</sub> - **z**<sub>k</sub>| (k =1,2,...)

Because *K* is compact (continues as above).

I've continued past this; it still puzzles me.

Comment: You have to tell us something about the ${\bf z}_k$.

Comment: I'd think so! I can make a simple case with a scalar y and z for which this doesn't follow. Is it possible I've found a typo?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f: \>(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)$ is not Lipschitz with respect to $y$ on $K$. Then there are sequences $(x_k,y_k)_{k\geq0}$ and $(x_k, z_k)_{k\geq0}$ on $K$ with
$$\bigl|f(x_k,y_k)-f(x_k,z_k)\bigr|\geq k|y_k-z_k|\qquad(k\geq0)\ .$$
As $K$ is compact there are a "selection sequence" $j\mapsto k_j$ and points $(x_*,y_*)$, $(x_*,z_*)\in K$ such that 
$$(x_{k_j},y_{k_j})\to(x_*,y_*),\quad (x_{k_j},z_{k_j})\to(x_*,z_*)\qquad(j\to\infty)\ .$$
Write $x_{k_j}=:x_j$, and similarly $y_j$, $z_j$ in the sequel. As $f$ is bounded on $K$ there is an $M>0$ such that
$$2M\geq\bigl|f(x_j,y_j)-f(x_j,z_j)\bigr|\geq k_j|y_j-z_j|\geq j\>|y_j-z_j|\qquad(j\geq0) .$$
This implies $y_*=z_*$.

Comment: Ah! This is true for any given M, no matter how large the k, and so the difference goes to zero as M/k goes to zero. I'm beginning to see the light. (I'll figure out the problem with my so-called counter-example on my own.) Thanks! This was very helpful.